# Get posts from different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So, i have 100 posts from 10 users, and i want to get a collection of 5 posts, but always from different user.

So `Post.where(active: true).order(:created_at).limit(5)...` works.

Any help?

Comment: in SQL, SELECT DISTINCT ON (column_1) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can select distinct User IDs:

```
Post.select("DISTINCT(user_id)").where(active: true).limit(5)
```

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what i need: Getting 5 posts, always from 5 different authors.

Comment: Updated, assuming your Post model has a `user_id` column

Comment: PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list